# can't find gem ruby-debug-ide (>= 0.a) with executable rdebug-ide (Gem::GemNotFoundException)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to run a Ruby app I downloaded from Github in Virtual Studio Code. I'm pretty clueless but I followed the documentation and got as far this error when I try to run the rails dev server:

/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:265:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem ruby-debug-ide (>= 0.a) with executable rdebug-ide (Gem::GemNotFoundException) from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:284:in` activate_bin_path'
from /usr/local/bin/rdebug-ide:23:in `'

Can anyone please help me understand what this means and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the gem to your computer?
Try running: `gem install ruby-debug-ide`

This would install the gem on your system and the issue should not happen anymore.